# AS3 Accessing Monostate instance child is null

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, monostate

I have an instance of Main that I should be able to access anywhere.
If I want to access a variable on level I should be able do:

_root.level.my_value

However .level is showing up null when I call _root.level in my map.

Main.as (Class Document)

```
package{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  public class Main extends MovieClip{

  //Monostate
  private static var _instance:Main;
  public static function get instance():Main { return _instance; }

  public var level:MovieClip;

  public function Main(){
    _instance = this; //Monostate
    this.level = new Level();
  }
}} //package / class
```

Level.as

```
package{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  public class Map extends MovieClip{

  private var _root:MovieClip;

  public function Map(){
    _root = Main.instance
    trace(_root);
    trace(_root.level); //This should not be null
  }
}} //package / class
```

Comment: is this all the code you have that interacts with Main?  I don't see anything wrong with what's shown.

Answer (score 0):

You are never instantiating your `_instance`, so `level` never gets set.

Your static getter should probably be something more like this:

```
public static get instance():Main {
    if(!_instance){
        _instance = new Main();
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

Comment: I think the assumption is that `Main` is the document class - though I suppose that is just an assumption